# Why am I unable to modify a list element at the beginning?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list and I would like to make a new list where `newlist[i] = 'literal' + oldlist[i]`.

I have tried code like:

```
i = 1
for elem in oldlist:
 newlist[i] = 'literal' + oldlist[i]
 i += 1

i = 1
for elem in newlist:
 elem = 'literal' + oldlist[i]
 i += 1
```

and many similar attempts yet keep getting errors such as "can't assign to function call" and others. How should my code be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are zero-based meaning the first item in the list is at index `0`.

e.g.,

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

print(l[0]) # 1
print(l[1]) # 2
```

You are starting your indexing at `1` hence your first item never gets changed.

---

Though your code doesn't fit the canonical "indexed-loop" format.  It should look more like this:

```
for i in range(len(oldlist)):
    newlist[i] = 'literal' + oldlist[i]
```

But an even better way to do this is to use a list comprehension:

```
newlist = ['literal' + olditem for olditem in oldlist]
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about list comprehension! This is a very useful concept I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension.

```
newlist = ['literal' + x for x in oldlist]
```

Answer (score 1):

because the `elem` is the value in the list and not a reference to the location in the list. (i reference the second example you have)

Answer (score 1):

Try a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [item + literal for item in oldlist]
```

Also, remember that list indices are numbered starting at zero, which means that the maximum index equals `len(list) - 1`